# iDangerous Swiper last clicked element roll back slider

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

On my site I use [iDangerous Swiper Slider](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper). And have

options:

```
slidesPerGroup:6, 
loop:false
```

on click on last slide(№14) slider swipe to left. How to remove this action? Help please..

You can see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/riff/UNsEu/)

Here initialization code:

```
var navSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-nav',{
    mode:'horizontal',
    speed:500,
    calculateHeight:true,
    simulateTouch:true,
    slidesPerView:6,
    slidesPerGroup:6,
    watchActiveIndex:true
});
```

Comment: Solution from developer of Swiper slider: "Grab the swiper's lib from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNsEu/2/).
I've made some changes there and now it is fixed for you" 

[Link on github](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/545#issuecomment-31847176)

Answer (score 0):

Remove slidesPerGroup:6, property and try:)

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, including what that does.

Comment: This solution will help only in case when no matter how much slides should be scrolled. Unfortunately slidesPerGroup:6 property is necessary for me.